# Laravel package permission denied problem

Tags: php, laravel, permissions

I cloned my group project and ran `composer install` then this error occurred:

```
require(C:\xampp\htdocs\hrm\vendor\milantarami\nepali-calendar\src./../config/nepali-calendar.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I gave full permission to that file (even the root folder of that file) but again it shows me permission denied even though I am the administrative user.

But the same project ran without errors in my group member's computer (OS: Windows 11)

OS: Windows 11

[image: problem Screenshot]

[image: Current permission screenshot]

Comment: Use WSL not plain windows, you will have this type of headaches every time